# gcloud ml vision and multiple commands

Tags: gcloud

Does anyone know of a way of invoking gcloud ml vision with both the detect-labels and suggest-crops commands together. I can do these separately but am having difficult matching up the suggested-crops responses and the detect-labels responses. I am running gcloud from a shell script (linux, opensuse) so I have multiple outputs. Also I always seem to get single suggested crops even when multiple labels are produced.

Answer (score 0):

`suggest-crop` "returns the coordinates of a bounding box that surrounds the dominant object or face in an image." That is to say, it only returns one bounding box, and that bounding box doesn't necessarily correspond to any particular label returned by `detect-labels`. In fact, the labels returned by `detect-labels` don't correspond to any particular bounding box in general. If you're looking for bounding boxes corresponding to particular features, you can use the other `gcloud ml vision detect-` commands. For example, to get the coordinates of the bounding boxes of the faces in an image, you can use:

`gcloud ml vision detect-faces my_image.jpg --format="yaml(responses[].faceAnnotations[].boundingPoly.vertices)"`

which gives you an output like:

`responses:
- faceAnnotations:
  - boundingPoly:
      vertices:
      - x: 113
        y: 63
      - x: 458
        y: 63
      - x: 458
        y: 463
      - x: 113
        y: 463`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was making some assumptions about what suggest-crop does. It looks like detect-labels dos not return enough information to get a bounding poly. Shame.